# Mysql: create columns from select statement

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I was wondering if you could create columns based on the result from a Select statement.

```
Table 1:

availableColumns
-----------------
column1 -> record 1
column2 -> record 2
column3 -> record 3
```

So if I did a Select availableColumns From Table1, how could I create a table that has then the following structure, the results must be used to create columns:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
```

If I try:

```
CREATE TABLE test SELECT availableColumns FROM table1
```

I get the following:

```
Column
------
Column1
Column2
Column3
```

So instead of columns, I get my result as rows which I don't want.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a list of columns for a specific table by selecting them from `Information Schema` table

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='tablename';
```

To create the table just use it

```
CREATE TABLE test  SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tablename';
```

Just change `'databasename'` and `'tablename'` to fit your actual database and table

Comment: But that doesn't add those columns as columns to a new table :) The result of that query should be used to create the columns of my new table.

Comment: The results are then being inserted as records in 1 column, instead of creating 10 columns :)

Comment: @darkownage i just tested and it's working, it creates a table with all columns selected from previuos table. You just need to change 'databasename' and 'tablename'